# How would you pass arguments to a script being passed as an argument?

Tags: python, node.js, bash, paraview

Basically the title, I don't know how to pass an argument to a script that is being passed as an argument in a shell command. Take the command below for example:

$someexe --arg-for-someexe scriptA.py

somexe is going to read from scriptA and perform a bunch of tasks and then spit out some data into a destination file hard-coded into scriptA. How would I pass the destination file into scriptA as a command line argument? In python I know I can get arguments using sys.argv[i] but someexe will also try to grab those arguments and could cause problems. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: how do you run `scriptA.py` ? Maybe you should use quotation marks `"scriptA.py arg1 arg2"` and you get it as one string which you can run. Or maybe you should create `--args-for-script "arg1 arg2"` in `someexe` and get arguments in separated string ?

Comment: I think this is probably off-topic for stackoverflow as this has to do with shell scripts, not with programming.

Comment: I can move this question somewhere else if need be. It does have to do with programming though, my ultimate goal is to call this command with a NodeJS app but if I know how to run this on the cmd line then I know how to run it with Node so I figured that part was irrelevant. @furas if I wrap up the arguments for scriptA into one string then it won't run at all right? I doubt someexe will be able to grab the python script out of a string. I don't have much control over someexe so I'm not sure if the 2nd option will work either.

Comment: I would think the issue itself (how to pass command parameters in an os shell) is not directly about programming.  It's about OS command shells and how you package things in them to get them passed through the way you want.  The appropriate forum for that would probably be whatever OS your shell is in.  Here's [Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: all depends - for example in python you have commands which can run string with arguments `"scriptA.py arg1 arg2 --other-arg arg3"` but there are commands which need it as a list `["scriptA.py", "arg1", "arg2", "--other-arg", "arg3"]`. The same can be in someexe - it may work with arguments in string or it may treat this string as one long name of program and it will have problem to run it.

Comment: you can also create new script which runs command `scriptA.py arg1 arg2 --other-arg arg3` and then you can run this new script without parameters because you have parameters inside script - so you can run `someexe --arg-for-someexe new_script.py`

Comment: sweet, that seems like it would work. I'll try that out, thank you!

Comment: Can the arguments to scriptA contain space characters? If so, it is easy to mess up something in someexe, if you try to split or join the arguments there. I would try not to touch the arguments in someexe - just pass them unaltered to scriptA. I would use `subprocess.run` in someexe to execute the command as a list of strings, but you could also use  `os.system` if you decide to pass the entire command as one string from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that:

Caller script (scripta.py):

```
import os
def main(args):
    os.system('python scriptb.py' + ' ' + str(args))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    main(args)
```

Receiver script (scriptb.py):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    print(args)
```

To call script a - say in a terminal:

```
python scripta.py arg1 42 arg2 43
```

Will print in scriptb.py terminal:

```
['[arg1,', '42,', 'arg2,', '43]']
```

os.system() spawns it in a separate shell/process. May or not be what you want.

Comment: This is clever, I will give this a try later today. Thanks!

Comment: I'd highly advise to head the advice of the official docs and use `subprocess` instead of `os.system` https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system

Comment: and do `subprocess.run(['python scriptb.py', *args])`, to above answer is sensitive to word-splitting